# SQL - WHERE on new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table with 3 columns: Id, Price, Total.
I'm writing this sql statement:

```
SELECT Id, Price, Total,
CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
     WHEN [Total] IS NOT NULL '1' 
     ELSE ''
END AS NewColumnName
FROM Table
```

If I run this sql, I have no error. But if I add a Where, like this:
WHERE NewColumnName= '1' the server return an error: the name of column NewColumnName is not valid.

Please help me!
Thanks a lot!!
RM

Comment: BTW - The second `WHEN` and the `ELSE` parts of the `CASE` statement are a bit redundant. A value is either `null` or it isn't, there is no third option. So the `CASE` statement could be simplified to `CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this way?

```
select *
from (
  SELECT Id, Price, Total,
  CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
       WHEN [Total] IS NOT NULL '1' 
       ELSE ''
  END AS NewColumnName
  FROM Table
) x
where 
  NewColumnName= '1'
```

Comment: I'm certain that `ELSE` is a waste of typing and processor cycles.

Comment: You are right. I assume the original query is only an example. And I planned to not change it.

Comment: I guess its more a comment for the OP @user2657115

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT Id, Price, Total,
CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
     WHEN [Total] IS NOT NULL '1' 
END AS NewColumnName
FROM Table
WHERE CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
     WHEN [Total] IS NOT NULL '1' 
END = '1'
```

Comment: why not just `WHERE [Total] IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Jodrell - sure! even better :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally use a subquery,

```
SELECT Id, Price, Total, NewColumnName
    FROM ( 
        SELECT
                    Id,
                    Price,
                    Total,
                    CASE
                        WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
                        ELSE '1'
                    END [NewColumnName]
            FROM
                    Table) [WithNew]
     WHERE
         NewColumnName = '1';
```

or in your case you could do,

```
SELECT
            Id,
            Price,
            Total,
            1 [NewColumnName]
    FROM
            Table
    WHERE
            Total IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]

WITH cte as (
SELECT [AddressID], [AddressLine1]
        , CASE WHEN [City] = 'Bothell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [NewColumn]
FROM Person.Address )

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE [NewColumn] = 1
```

So yours would be re-written like this:

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT Id, Price, Total,
CASE WHEN [Total] IS NULL THEN '0'
     WHEN [Total] IS NOT NULL '1' 
     ELSE ''
END AS NewColumnName
FROM Table) 

SELECT * FROM CTE where [NewColumnName] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use NewColumnName in the WHERE Clause. You will have to use the CASE statement again in WHERE Clause or do what @Lajos suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your query like this:

```
SELECT Id, Price, Total,
FROM Table
WHERE Total IS NOT NULL
```

That's doing the same thing, except without the case statement.